# Losing Context User After Custom SAML Auth Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm implementing a SAML2 auth consumer pattern without a 3rd party lib like ITfoxtec or Sustainsys, it seemed like overkill. Whereby an external service handles the authentication, certificates and minting of the SAML markup with all the pertinent roles and attributes I can use for authz. They then post that to my controller and I can derive my authz and set my context user.

I can parse the SAML and create my claims identity. I set the HttpContext.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal to this new ClaimsPrincipal(userClaimsIdentity). However, **once I redirect out of this controller to an auth'ed endpoint, the Context.User.Identity loses all claims and IsAuthenticated is false.**

```
public class ReadSamlController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost()]
        public ActionResult Index([FromBody] XmlDocument samlResponse)
        {
            var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(samlResponse.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
            manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
            manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");


            var assertionNode = samlResponse.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion", manager);
            if (assertionNode == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to obtain the SAML Assertion for the request.");
            }
            
            var saml2Serializer = new Saml2Serializer();

            var xmlNodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(assertionNode);

            var samlAssertion = saml2Serializer.ReadAssertion(xmlNodeReader);

            if (samlAssertion == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to serialize the assertion into a Saml2Assertion");
            }

            var samlAttributes = samlAssertion.Statements
                                            .Single(att => att.GetType() == typeof(Saml2AttributeStatement)) as Saml2AttributeStatement;


            var userClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("ReleaseDash");
            foreach (var rdClaimTypeKey in RdClaimTypes.Keys)
            {
                var samlAttr =
                    samlAttributes.Attributes.Single(
                        attr => attr.Name.Equals(rdClaimTypeKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                foreach (var samlAttrValue in samlAttr.Values)
                {
                    userClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(rdClaimTypeKey, samlAttrValue));
                }

            }

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(userClaimsIdentity); // the user is set up correctly, IsAuthenticated, role claims etc is all there

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

It seems like I'm missing setting up a UserManager or SignInManager that can "persist" this across the session context. I've setup a bunch of custom auth code for a scheme and set that up in Startup like so

```
services
  .AddAuthentication()
  .AddScheme<ReleaseDashAuthenticationOptions, ReleaseDashAuthenticationHandler>("ReleaseDash", _ => { });
```

In my Auth Handler when I peek at the Context Endpoint, I see the Context Identity is missing all the attributes I set in my ReadSaml Controller.

```
protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var endpoint = Context.GetEndpoint();
            
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I terribly overengineered this. I turned to the Cookie Scheme and everything worked when I added

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

before I redirected in my ReadSaml controller...ahhhh